# Why is this simple animation not working on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios7, uiviewanimation

In my project I have a simple animation, I just move a view from left to right. This works fine in iOS 6, but when I run in iOS 7 it does not do anything. Does someone know why? If the animation is very simple how can I fix this for iOS 7? My code is:

```
- (void) showAnimation
 {
    if (IS_IPAD())
    {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:50.0f 
                             delay:1
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                        animations:^{
                                         ViewBOLIVIA.frame = CGRectMake(1024,0,  ViewBOLIVIA.frame.size.width, ViewBOLIVIA.frame.size.height);
                                    } completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        if (IS_IPHONE_5)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:50.0f 
                                  delay:1 
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat 
                              animations:^{
                                               ViewBOLIVIA.frame = CGRectMake(568,0,  ViewBOLIVIA.frame.size.width, ViewBOLIVIA.frame.size.height);
                                          } completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
             [UIView animateWithDuration:50.0f 
                                   delay:1 
                                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                              animations:^{
                                               ViewBOLIVIA.frame = CGRectMake(480,0,  ViewBOLIVIA.frame.size.width, ViewBOLIVIA.frame.size.height);
                                          } completion:nil];
        }
    }
 }
```

I did update and Im using Xcode 5 and iOS 7 so any help guys, do you know how fix this?

Comment: are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: no, I'm not using Auto Layout

Comment: Have you used breakpoints to verify the code is being reached?

Comment: yes Im using breakpoints and Nslogs show me the new position of the View, but I dont know why is not showing anything O_o?

Comment: are you absolutely positive that transitioning to Xcode 5 hasn't made your project to adopt Auto Layout?

Comment: thanks for comment bneely & Gabriele, but I'm absolutely sure, I have unchecked "Use Autolayout", and the storyboard is the same after update to Xcode 5, if in Xcode 4 and iOS 6 run, what could be wrong in the update?

Comment: I have the same problem. None of the animations are working. basically the same code.

Answer (score 16):

OK I think I resolved it. Before iOS 7 it was okay to have animations running in viewDidLoad with storyboards. If you move your animation calls to `- (void)viewDidAppear` then they should start working again. So in your case you will want to call `[self showAnimation];` in `- (void)viewDidAppear`.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear{
   [self showAnimation];
}
```

Comment: thanks jimbob but not work for me, I will continue trying to find a solution, I check with breakpoints and NSLogs, if call the method in viewDidLoad and viewdidapear, and runs but does not show, i don't know why? T_T

Comment: have you tried using UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState?

Comment: Sorry Dude, not working, & for the animation, I need UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat, because I need in a loop or infinite run animation meanwhile I use the app U_U

Answer (score 0):

I found placing the code in this method works.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    menuView.alpha = 0;
    topLabel.alpha = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
       menuView.alpha = 1;
       topLabel.alpha = 1;
    }];
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 }
```